# Config spec of the clearcase vi

Tags: java, hudson, clearcase, cleartool

I would like to know if below my need is possible in clearcase :

Say , I have 15 different views (**Dynamic or Snapshot**) created (**from different users/developers**), I want get the "config spec" using some kind of **cleartool command** (Without having to right click on the view and select the configspec from windows context menu).

Finally I would like to store/track all the config spec's from all the developers and apply the continuous integration (Hudson) build on all those config spec's. Yes , it is maintenance project and need to create multiple branches on different views.

Hope my expectation is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two commands for accessing/editing a (dynamic or snapshot view) are:

- [cleartool catcs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_catcs.htm)
- [cleartool edcs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_edcs.htm)

Once you have accessed a config spec, you can save it in a file in order to apply it again to any other view, with **[cleartool setcs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm)**:

```
cleartool setcs -tag aViewTag /path/to/a/configSpec/file
```

You can then ask Hudson to reuse those pre-configured views: see [Hudson integration with UCM ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892508/hudson-integration-with-ucm-clearcase) (for UCM, but also valid for base ClearCase views).
See the [Hudson ClearCase Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin) for more.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

cleartool catcs will get config spec