# Jenkins clearcase plugin config spec - loading files

Tags: plugins, jenkins, config, clearcase

I am using jenkins to build my project. My source code is in clearcase. I want to get the latest code from latest local code and make a build. All the setup worked

ClearCase repository Structure - 2 projects.

Main_Projects
    -Project_1
       --**Project_1_Ver1**
           ---Project_1_Ver1_TST
           ----Project_1_Ver1_LCL
       --**Project_1_Ver2**
           ---Project_1_Ver2_TST
           ----Project_1_Ver2_LCL

-ProjectTwo
       --Project_2_Ver1
           ---Project_2_Ver1_TST
           ----Project_2_Ver1_LCL

JENKINS Project - Source Management
**Base ClearCase** 
view tag: Jenkins_Project_1_Ver1_LCL
view path: Jenkins_Project_1_Ver1_LCL

This is working config spec 
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../Project_1_Ver1_LCL/LATEST
element * .../Project_2_Ver1_LCL/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST

Load Rules
\Proj1
\proj2

I had to point to new version for one project and I updated the config spec as follows

view tag: Jenkins_Project_1_Ver**2**_LCL
view path: Jenkins_Project_1_Ver**2**_LCL

element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../Project_1_Ver**2**_LCL/LATEST
element * .../Project_2_Ver1_LCL/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST

Load Rules
\Proj1
\proj2

After this change, jenkins clearcase plugin does not get the code for the Project_1_Ver**2**_LCL stream any more.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a parent folder labelled with V1 only and not V2 (which would make all V2 sub-elements inaccessible), add a V1 rule (*after* the V2 one)

```
element * .../Project_1_Ver2_LCL/LATEST
element * .../Project_1_Ver1_LCL/LATEST
```

Another approach would be to make sure the baseline V2 is a full one, not an incremental one. That way, its associated label would be present on *all* the elements of the component.

Comment: Project_1_Ver1 and Project_1_Ver2 are sibling folder  under Project_1. A new  project_1_ver2 is created from Project_1_ver1_TST baseline.

Comment: I understand, but try it anyway, especially if the baselines are incremental instead of full.

Comment: That worked. Firstly thanks very much. Secondly.. When the baseline was made, I did see my colleague making Baseline Type: Full. I am a little confused now. Anyhow I have to read more on Config_Spec. Can you please recommend any resource.

Comment: @user418836 can you check the nature of those baselines? (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24100191/6309: `cleartool describe -l baseline:aBaseline@\aPVob`

Comment: @user418836 regarding the config spec, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16001035/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3749230/6309, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805606/6309.